# How to create a PowerShell function to delete accounts from AD recycle bin

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the following code. I am trying to clean up deleted accounts from AD.

```
Function Del-User() {
    $To_Be_Deleted = (Get-ADObject -Filter 'isDeleted -eq $True -and -not (isRecycled -eq $true) -and name -ne "Deleted Objects" -and lastKnownParent -eq "CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local"'-includeDeletedObject).DistinguishedName

    foreach ($d in $To_Be_Deleted) {
        Remove-ADObject -Identity $d
    }
}

Del-User
```

When I pipe the output directly to `Remove-ADObject`, it works, but when I try to use the function it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
At C:\Users\administrator.example\Documents\del.ps1:18 char:9
+         Remove-ADObject -Identity $d
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=user name...example,DC=local:ADObject) [Remove-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Directory object not found,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADObject

Remove-ADObject : Directory object not found
```

Comment: Why? Objects are purged automatically from the AD recycle bin [after their tombstone expires](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/08/27/the-ad-recycle-bin-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/).

Comment: i got the requirement, why I don't know ...... I just need to provide the solution.

Comment: Tell whoever gave you the task that the requirement doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Remove-ADObject -Identity $d -IncludeDeletedObjects

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/remove-adobject?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Remove-ADObject
[-WhatIf]
[-Confirm]
[-AuthType ]
[-Credential ]
[-Identity] 
[-IncludeDeletedObjects]
[-Partition ]
[-Recursive]
[-Server ]
[]